# Set folder name in Outlook address book programmatically with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

We have one big empty Outlook Public Folder called Intermediarios, which stores individual folders with the name of our company branches. Inside each one of them we have our insurance agent's contacts.

To display a public folder in your Outlook address book, you need to right click properties each one, go to the Outlook Address Book tab, check the box and type the desired name that the folder will be named in the Address Book.

Since there are 20 branches, i want to do a vbs script that does this automatically. I have the following script which works, but i want to set a different name for each folder to better describe what they contain, without renaming the public folder.

Current script is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objOL, objNS, objFolder
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'18 is olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders representing all public folders
Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Intermediarios").Folders("Cabimas")
    objFolder.ShowAsOutlookAB = True
```

I need to put something before the last name to set the name of the address book entry, but i don't know how. I tried both objFolder.Description and objFolder.Name , but the last one actually renames the public folder which is something i don't want.

Can this be done? I tried browsing the AddressList and AddressEntries objects but i don't see anything that will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `MAPIFolder.AddressBookName` property.

Comment: i'm such a klutz. objFolder.AddressBookName was just waiting for me to be used. Thanks